# 2D Graphics with matrix transformation too small for integer mouseevents?

Tags: vb.net, 2d, mouseevent, gdi+

I'm designing a simple app to display some Cartesian type graphics using DrawLine() and DrawEllipse() functions into a PictureBox control. To make the coordinate system  more "real-world" instead of the picture box I am using a matrix to flip the Y axis, scale everything down and reposition it so that (0,0) is at the center of the screen and (+2,+2) is at the upper right corner. All works well for drawing of graphics. However, in trying to read mouse events it appears that the MouseEventArgs variable (returned by most Mouse events) returns the mouse position X and Y as integers. I am properly using an inverted matrix to retrieve the coordinates at the scaled values, but at the scale I am using, this won't work as integers as I require screen positions in fractional values (1.5, 1.6, etc).

Is there no way to retrieve the mouse values as a floating point or double/decimal value that will give the "resolution" I require?

Some code fragements:

--Globally

```
Private MyTransform As Matrix
```

--Within the picturebox

```
Paint() event  
Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics  
Dim mx As New Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0) 'Y-axis orientation flipped to match Cartesian plane  
mx.Translate(PictureBox.Width / 2, -PictureBox.Height / 2) 'Move 0,0 to lower left corner  
mx.Scale(100, 100)  
G.Transform = mx  
MyTransform = G.Transform
```

'All drawing is performed at this point and works fine.

--Within the MouseDown event

```
MyTransform.Invert()  
'Here is the issue--the Mouse points returned, being integers, cannot properly  
'show the mouse point if the transformation matrix has scaled up the drawing space at all.  
e.Location.x 'is an integer, so it cannot show .01 as the proper mouse location within the transformed viewspace.  
e.Location.y 'same issue.  
MyTransform.Invert()
```

I've looked for a cartesian coordinate-based picturebox alternative to no avail, and Charting components won't work because they require the points being drawn be contained in their own proprietary containers/sets. I'm doing all the drawing myself with GDI-type methods. The only alternative seems to be to avoid doing the transformations with vb and doing all the translation/untranslation myself, unless someone has an alternative or example to suggest....?

Comment: Do you have some code to reproduce the effect?

Comment: The reason they are in Integers is because they represent the pixel locations, so some other math equation will be needed to suite your needs. If you detail what the changes are to be then maybe we can assist with that.

Comment: Yes, I understand the reasoning, which works well if the viewspace was "fixed" and you were to not scale up the drawing space--hence keeping them integers. However, scaling up the drawing space using the matrix/transformation methods makes it painfully obvious that the values should to be fractional. I've added some code fragments and more info to the original post.

Comment: Then yes you have to do the math yourself if your not working in a 1/1 plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `Scale` as a property. Then as you change the scale you apply a function to the mouse coordinates difference. Example will use a 10/1 plane so the `Scale` will be `10`.

```
Private Property Scale As Single
```

Function:

```
Private Function CorrectForScale(coord As Integer) As Single
   Return (coord / Scale)
End Function
```

Now if the difference in distance between mouse position = 3 then the result after the function would be `0.3`.

Comment: Thanks, but the question isn't really about how to do it (because there's a lot more involved than just scaling) it's about either having a way to get higher resolution numbers from the event or if, without an alternative, I'm forced to do the math myself.

Comment: Right, there is a way. It's going to be math like above. Sorry there is not an easier way.